# Exporting Favorites from Character Viewer

Tags: macos, keyboard, mojave, internationalization

I would like to export the list of Favorites in Character Viewer (which can be launched by selecting "Show Emoji & Symbols" in the menu bar icon for the input source) and import it into a different Mac.  Where is this list of Favorites stored?

I am using macOS Mojave 10.14.2.

[image: Favorites in Character Viewer]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Favorites are stored in a plist specific to your user.  The file can be found at:

> /Users/{YOUR-USERNAME}/Library/Preferences/com.apple.CharacterPicker.plist

My current favorites are `…` and , and the file looks like this when opened in Xcode:

[image: image of my com.apple.CharacterPicker.plist]

You may have to restart to see it change.

Comment: Thanks!  This solution works for me.

Comment: @dashmile consider closing the questin

Comment: @ankiiiiiii. A user does not have the ability to close a question, the system does this automatically if the situation warrants. Have a look at: [What does it mean if a question is "closed" or "on hold"?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)

Comment: Is it OK to use the same plist file in another machine with a different version of macOS (Catalina for example) than the original (High Sierra)?

Comment: I think what ankii meant was accepting the solution, not closing the question

Comment: somewhat related to the question raised by @Alper, I found that copying the com.apple.CharacterPicker.plist from one mac to another successfully transferred all emoji "Favorites" after restarting.  One was a MacBool Pro 2015 and the other a an M1 MacAir 2020, both running OS 11.4