# Using Favorites from Character Viewer on another Mac

Tags: internationalization

I would like to use the list of customized Favorites in Character Viewer from my Macintosh on my co-worker's Mac.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Hmm this one is similar from 2 months ago and no answer there: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/348064/exporting-favorites-from-character-viewer

Comment: Thanks steve for pointing this out and Linda for bumping the request. I’ve put down a bounty to see if someone can get us an answer.